# RobotFramework Opening Email Links using robotframework-imaplibrary2

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

Currently using a robotframework-imaplibrary2 [a extension of robot framework]

To open emails sent, I just want to open the link from the sent email in a using the the normal robot framework selenium functions

Is this possible?

```
 Email Verification
Open Mailbox    host=imap.hiddeb.com    user=fsf@fsefesf.com   password=sfefsff
${LATEST} =    Wait For Email    sender=sfefsefs@sfefsf.com   timeout=300
  ${HTML} =    Open Link From Email    ${LATEST}
```

The library contains this

```
${HTML} =   Open Link From Email    ${LATEST}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What's stopping you from using "the normal seleniums stuff" to open the email? And if you want to use selenium, why are you showing code that uses IMAP?

Comment: This is a library extension of robot framework which allows you to open imap servers and open the body, get the url. Essentially i want to get the URL from the body of the email sent and then parse that back to the browser.

Then do normal function such as 
   Open Browser    https://etc.com  ${BROWSER}

Comment: The question is still unclear. What's stopping you from getting the link from the body? What have you tried? Have you tried writing a keyword in python to take the html body and parse it?

Comment: ${HTML} =   Open Link From Email    ${LATEST}, seems to work but i cant work out how to get that URL and then open the browser with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looking at the implementation of the keywords](https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-imaplibrary/blob/master/src/ImapLibrary/__init__.py), I'd say this has nothing to with selenium.

What seems to happen is, you need an email that is in HTML format (not plain text). Then you need the *index* of that email, which is in your case stored in variable `${LATEST}`

Calling `Open link from Email    ${LATEST}` uses the first link (that is the default behaviour) that is found in that email and opens the url and gets the HTML content of that website. There does not seem to be any browser or webdriver involved.

However, if you like to open a link in a browser, I would try the keyword [`Get Links from Email`](https://rickypc.github.io/robotframework-imaplibrary/doc/ImapLibrary.html#Get%20Links%20From%20Email):

```
${ALL_LINKS}    Get Links from Email    ${LATEST}
SeleniumLibrary.Go To    ${ALL_LINKS}[0]
```

**Disclaimer:** Since I do not have any test-email server available, my suggestion might require adjustments.

Comment: *NOTE*: Need to open browser before `Go To`.